# System.ArgumentNullException when creating a call expression on Xname.Get

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I am trying to create a dynamic query on a XElement source by using expression trees. A part of this query needs to compare the value of an XElement Attribute and it is when constructing the expressions for obtaining the attribute value I am getting the ArgumentNullException. It is connected to the Expression.Call for XName.Get but I do not know how to interpret the exception in for this case.

PS: the constant expressions in the code are there just for this example.

The code:

```
var value = 
            Expression.Property(
                Expression.Call(Expression.Parameter(typeof(XElement), "attr1"), typeof(XElement).GetMethod("Attribute"), 
                    Expression.Call(typeof(XName).GetMethod("Get", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly), Expression.Constant("id"))), 
            "Value");
```

Comment: There is no public **instance** `Get` method on `XName` type.

Comment: Sorry, was a leftover from blind coding when trying to find the error. Anyhow, even when removing flag that entails that, I still get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typeof(XName).GetMethod(
    "Get", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
```

This is your problem, as PetSerAl already pointed out. But removing `BindingFlags.Instance` won't solve anything, you need to specify that you want a static method:

```
typeof(XName).GetMethod(
    "Get", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
```

This still won't work, it throws `AmbiguousMatchException`, but we're getting closer. Your `Call` has a single `string` parameter, so we need to specify we want that overload of `XName.Get`:

```
typeof(XName).GetMethod("Get", new[] { typeof(string) })
```

(We don't need to specify `BindingFlags`, because the default works fine.)

With this modification, your snippet seems to work fine.

Comment: That did it. Thank you very mutch!

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess, because this expression tree as shown isn't compilable.

The problem is probably because of your `Expression.Parameter` call. Parameters must be reference equal to whatever is passed in. The descriptive name ("attr1") is only for debugging purposes.

If that doesn't solve your problem, then please post the full tree (or at least more of it).